# How to calculate the transalation and/or rotation of two images using fourier transaform?

Tags: image-processing, fourier-transform

I need find the translation and/or rotation of an image and himself translated and/or rotated (x0, y0) px and/or J degrees. Given the two images I need to find N.

Answer (score 5):

The classic reference for this problem is [Reddy et al., An FFT-Based Technique for Translation,
Rotation, and Scale-Invariant Image Registration](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/506761). The basic idea builds on the well-known properties of the FFT, that a displacement is reflected in a phase shift of the same magnitude, so that you just need to recover the phase shift to estimate the displacement.

Concretely, if the FFT of an image $f(x, y)$ is $F(\xi, \eta)$, then the FFT of $f^{'}(x, y) = f(x-x_0, y-y_0)$ is $e^{-j2\pi (x_0 \xi + y_0 \eta)}F(\xi, \eta)$, so that

$$
e^{-j2\pi (x_0 \xi + y_0 \eta)} = \frac{F(\xi, \eta)\bar F^{'}(\xi, \eta)}{F(\xi, \eta)F^{'}(\xi, \eta)}
$$

where $\bar F$ is the conjugate. In the paper, this approach is extended to get estimates of rotations and scaling along the x,y axis.

Comment: Thank. That's excelente. Is there a clear definition for the rotatation? Do you have a Python code?

Comment: I do not fully understand your question. The idea is that you have a reference image, and translations and rotations are relative to that reference image. Please go through the paper, and do not hesitate to ask if there are unclear issues. OpenCV provides an implementation. See cv::phaseCorrelate (https://docs.opencv.org/4.6.0/d7/df3/group__imgproc__motion.html#ga552420a2ace9ef3fb053cd630fdb4952)

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV (and Scikit-Image) only implement phase correlation (aka just the translation part). I couldn't find an implementation of translation **+ rotation** in any library from the Reddy et al. paper @jpmuc mentioned, so I implemented it here: https://gist.github.com/kwsp/8c660f7636c64f3f6ceaac900517f842

````py
"""
B. S. Reddy and B. N. Chatterji, “An FFT-based technique for translation, rotation, and scale-invariant image registration,” IEEE Transactions on Image Processing, vol. 5, no. 8, pp. 1266–1271, Aug. 1996, doi: 10.1109/83.506761.

Implemented in Numpy/OpenCV and Numpy/Scikit-Image

The OpenCV version is about 4 times faster than the Scikit-Image version.
"""
# Numpy/OpenCV implementation
import cv2
from scipy import signal
import scipy.fft as sfft
import numpy as np


# OpenCV implementation
def find_rotation_cv(img_ref: np.ndarray, img_moved: np.ndarray) -> float:
    h, w = img_ref.shape[:2]
    hamming_w = signal.windows.hamming(w)
    hamming_h = signal.windows.hamming(h)
    hamming = np.outer(hamming_h, hamming_w)

    F_ref = np.log(np.abs(sfft.fftshift(sfft.fft2(img_ref * hamming))))
    F_moved = np.log(np.abs(sfft.fftshift(sfft.fft2(img_moved * hamming))))

    center_x = w // 2
    center_y = h // 2
    radius = min(center_x, center_y)

    # Define the desired size of the output polar image
    polar_width = radius
    polar_height = int(np.ceil(radius * np.pi / 2))

    # Perform the polar transformation
    F_ref_warpped = cv2.warpPolar(
        F_ref, 
        (polar_width, polar_height), 
        (center_x, center_y), 
        radius, 
        cv2.WARP_POLAR_LOG + cv2.INTER_CUBIC + cv2.WARP_FILL_OUTLIERS
    )
    F_moved_warpped = cv2.warpPolar(
        F_moved, 
        (polar_width, polar_height), 
        (center_x, center_y), 
        radius, 
        cv2.WARP_POLAR_LOG + cv2.INTER_CUBIC + cv2.WARP_FILL_OUTLIERS
    )

    ret = cv2.phaseCorrelate(F_ref_warpped[:180], F_moved_warpped[:180])
    theta_shift = 360 / polar_height * -ret[0][1]
    return theta_shift



from skimage.transform import warp_polar
from skimage.registration import phase_cross_correlation


# scikit-image implementation
def find_rotation(img_ref: np.ndarray, img_moved: np.ndarray) -> float:
    h, w = img_ref.shape[:2]
    hamming_w = signal.windows.hamming(w)
    hamming_h = signal.windows.hamming(h)
    hamming = np.outer(hamming_h, hamming_w)

    F_ref = np.log(np.abs(sfft.fftshift(sfft.fft2(img_ref * hamming))))
    F_moved = np.log(np.abs(sfft.fftshift(sfft.fft2(img_moved * hamming))))

    F_ref_warpped = warp_polar(F_ref, scaling="log")
    F_moved_warpped = warp_polar(F_moved, scaling="log")

    ret = phase_cross_correlation(F_ref_warpped[:180, ], F_moved_warpped[:180, ])
    return ret[0][0]
```
````